# Understanding Inflation at philosophical level?

Tags: philosophy-of-economics, economics

I came across this sentence at random "The Manhattan Project began modestly in 1939, but grew to employ more than 130,000 people and cost nearly US$2 billion (equivalent to about $23 billion in 2019)." Now reading the last part made me realize what a nuisance inflation is because for a given object, not only do I need to know its price but also the era to calculate the present day price (like if x represent the price in 1939, then multiply by 11.5 to get the present price). Wouldn't it be wonderful if the prices remains the same which got me thinking on why do price increase in the first place at a philosophical level. Based on my naive thinking I have following observation on economics:

1. If the resource is unlimited, then the price is free (eg air, sunlight)
2. If the resource is relatively large, then in short period, using it won't change it's quantity and hence the price should remain same as nothing has changed (for eg certain metals).
3. If there is breakthrough innovation (i.e. efficient method to get more from same), then prices should decrease.

Based on this observation lets apply it to case of developing an atom bomb in 1940. In 1939 it costs USD $2 Billion. The resource (like Uranium, metals etc) availability remain same on Earth (or better since with time we would develop technology to do more with same quantity), the human effort/labour required will also be same as we are creating the same object hence I see no reason for price increase. Then extrapolating it to 2019, I would see no reason on why it should in price by 11.5 times.

I was hoping to have a physics like system where measuring scales like distance in principle measure some true inherent value and is invariant under time (1km in 1939 is same as 1km in 2021). Likewise we could have standard currency which would measure true inherent value of a thing (like house or atom bomb) and should remain the same across all era.

P.S.

1. I know few would say that raw material price increase is the cause of increase in cost of atom bomb which then would prompt a reply from me that why would raw material price increase (basically shifting the question from making atom bombs to manufacturing the said raw material).
2. Economics noob here.

Comment: Inflation is more about the change in the value of the currency than in the value of commodities. The sentence you quoted is not comparing the cost of the Manhattan project in 1939 vs 2019, rather it is comparing the value of the US dollar in 1939 ve 2019. That being said, this isn’t really a philosophical question.

Comment: I do not think this is "philosophical" in the sense used on this site. "Philosophical reasons", as used colloquially, for inflation, or something else, simply mean underlying long term causes rather than more immediate surface ones, and their discussion still belongs to specific disciplines. So [Economics SE](https://economics.stackexchange.com/) is a more appropriate place for this question.